# How to test that a Backbone view event adds an item to a collection?

Tags: testing, backbone.js, coffeescript, bdd, jasmine

I am trying to spec the click event handler on the following Backbone view:

```
class ItemView extends Backbone.View
  events:
    "click": "addToCurrentlyFocusedList"

  addToCurrentlyFocusedList: (e) =>
    window.currentlyFocusedList.add @model
```

This is what I have:

```
describe "ItemView", ->
  beforeEach ->
    @item = new Backbone.Model
      id: 1
      name: "Item 1"
    @view = new ItemView model: @item

  describe "when clicked", ->
    it "adds the item to the currently focused list", ->
      window.currentlyFocusedList = sinon.stub()
      window.currentlyFocusedList.add = sinon.stub()
      @view.$el.trigger "click"
      expect(window.currentlyFocusedList.add).toHaveBeenCalledWith @item
```

This works but it bothers me for some reason. Maybe it feels too much like I am testing implementation.

One possible improvement I can see is moving the click event handler, the spec, and the `currentlyFocusedList` into a new view called `AppView`:

```
describe "AppView", ->
  beforeEach ->
    @view = new AppView

  it "adds a clicked item to the currently focused list", ->
    $clickedItem = @view.$(".item:first")
    $clickedItem.trigger "click"
    expect(@view.currentlyFocusedList.pluck('id')).toInclude $clickedItem.attr('data-id')
```

It's nice that this also removes `window` pollution. It also tests that the item really is added to the collection. That aside, is moving the event handler and spec into `AppView` better than my first approach? Is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: Subjective question. This probably belongs on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ or http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Cool. I didn't know about codereview.stackexchange.com. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

I would stub out window.currentlyFocusedList with a dummy Collection, and test that it was added there.  Something along these lines:

```
beforeEach ->
  @collection = new Backbone.Collection()
  spyOn(window, 'currentlyFocusedList').andReturn @collection

it "adds the item to the collection", ->
  @view.$el.click()
  expect(@collection).toInclude @item
```

This tests what your code *actually does*; the code for how adding an item to a collection affects the view lives somewhere else, and should be tested somewhere else.